# Mostrar una información un otra dependiendo de que hijo sea de una clase

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Tengo una clase, a la que llamaremos `Entidad` tal que así:

```
public class Entidad {

    protected String name;

    protected String notes;

    //Getters y setters

}
```

De la que extienden otras 2 clases, la primera es `Persona`

```
public class Persona extends Entidad {

    private String dni;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

E `Institucion`

```
public class Institucion extends Entidad {

    private String cif;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

El caso es que tengo una tabla donde muestro distintos registros y en el código solo uso entidad, habría alguna forma de mostrar esto:

```
<td th:text="${entidad.dni}"></td>
<td th:text="${entidad.cif}"></td>
```

En otras palabras, que si el elemento que hay agregado pertenece a la clase persona muestre el DNI y si es de la tabla Institucion muestre el CIF sin tener que comprobar en el código Java si es una entidad u otra o sin tener que poner un flag para comprobarlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sé si esto es lo que busca, pues hay partes de su pregunta que me hacen dudar.

Puede emplear algo así (adaptándolo):

```
<span th:if="${entidad instanceof T(su.project.Persona)}"     th:text="muestra dni"></span>
<span th:if="${entidad instanceof T(su.project.Institucion)}" th:text="muestra cif"></span>
```

> `T(name.of.class)` notación para definir una class

o

```
<span th:if="${entidad.class.name == 'su.project.Persona'}" th:text="muestra dni"></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que no estas aprovechando la clase base. Ambas clases tienen algo en comun que es su numero de identificacióno (o numero de documento) a pesar de que son de diferentes tipos (DNI, CIF)
Lo correcto a mi entender es esta clase base:

```
public enum TipoDoc {
    DNI, CIF
}    

public class Entidad {

    protected String name;

    protected String notes;

    protected String identificacion;

    protected TipoDoc tipo;

}
```

Donde la clase persona forzara el tipo a DNI e Institucion a CIF.

Otra alternativa es crear una clase abstracta que se llame Documento y que cada subclase represente un tipo especifico de documento con sus caracteristicas y que el método ToString() de cada clase sepa como representar en un String el documento.

```
public abstract class Documento {

   private String nroDocumento;

   protected Documento(String nroDocumento) {
        this.nroDocumento = nroDocumento 
   }

   public String getDocumento() {...}

   public abstract String getTipo();

   public ToString() {
        return getTipo() + " " + getDocumento();
   }

}

public class DniDocumento extends Documento {

   public DniDocumento(String nroDocumento) {
        super(nroDocumento);
   }

   public String getTipo() {
         return "DNI";
   }

}
```

De esta manera no hay condicionales que tengas que poner para distinguir una clase de otra al momento de imprimir una propiedad que ambos tipos tienen en comun. Las clases entonces quedarian asi:

```
public abstract class Entidad {

    protected String name;

    protected String notes;

    protected Documento documento;

    protected Entidad (String name, String notes, Documento documento) {
        this.name = name;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public Documento getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }
}

public class Persona extends Entidad {

    public Persona (String name, String notes, DniDocumento documento) {
        super(name, notes, documento);
    }

    // Opcional
    public DniDocumento getDocumento() {
        return (DniDocumento) documento;
    }
}
```

También se podrían usar clases genéricas, pero creo que así esta bien.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando polimorfismo, lo primero es que el padre sea *abstract*, y declara un método abstracto que te obligue a implementarlo en los que heredan:

```
public abstrac class Entidad {
    protected String name;
    protected String notes;

    // metodo abtracto retornar id
    public abstrac String mostrarId();

}
```

hijos

```
public class Persona extends Entidad {
    private String dni;
    // returnar id
    public String mostrarId(){
       return getDni();
    }

}
```

El otro:

```
public class Institucion extends Entidad {
    private String cif;
    // returnar id
    public String mostrarId(){
       return getCif();
    }

}
```

Para mostrar los datos, solo invocas al método abstracto:

```
System.out.print("DNI/CIF" + Entidad.mostrarId());
```

Dependiendo del objeto que sea, imprimirá el DNI o el CIF.